# Sharing the transaction between multiple components

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, components, transactionmanager

We are developing a java program which has lots of independent components(let's say A, B, C, D). We use Hibernate framework for database mapping. Some of them working on the same JVM process and some of them are working the different JVM process. All of these components have REST endpoints and has own entity map file. Each of these components talks to each other over the TCP. There is some business logic which required a few of these components work together. And the problem starts from here. Let's say component A is called. A start a new transaction and change some data on the database then calls the component B. When component B accepted the request it opens a new transaction and changes some information on the database and commit. After finishing its work return the result to the component A. Component A start again doing some operations but failed and rollback all changes what it has done and returns the response to the back. But the changes which component B did still there. This is a little illustration of our program. What we need what is the best approaches to handle this?

1. Somehow we share the transaction between all the components. So when the component gets request first check is there any active transaction for this request.
2. The second option is using the one component to all entity and all others use this. When the request comes we open a transaction, all components do their works and when we return the response we check if there is no any exception we commit otherwise rollback.

Is there any other way? Or what are the best practices using transaction between multiple components architecture system? What are the pros and cons using a single component to keep all entity information at one point? Any post, blogs, documentation, tutorial or book are acceptable. Or if it is ok you can share your experiments.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to implement 'Distributed Transactions'.

I recommend Spring if you have a Java application as it supports distributed transactions:
https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. But we want to do this without using spring.

Comment: What are you using for transaction management currently? Distributed transactions are quite tricky, Spring uses Atomikos or Bitronix embedded transaction manager's so you could try to use the same thing that Spring does yourself. Out of interest why do you want to avoid spring?

Comment: we are using the default one(JTA)